# Something went wrong with Facebook php sdk in yii

Tags: yii

I installed Facebook php sdk as stated in facebook official doc. Moreover, I loaded application configuration into Facebook\Facebook service and replaced required paramters with my own:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);
```

However, when I run the project, I got following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found in 
C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\blog\protected\controllers\PostController.php 
on line 49
```

I do not know why it is happening. How can i solve it?

Comment: How exactly did you install the Facebook sdk?

Comment: I have installed using composer